# Updating node.js possibly lead to npm error

Tags: node.js, npm

I recently updated the **node.js**  to the version 6.11.1. Got an error when accessing **npm**

When I tried to check the version of npm, the following error occurs

```
$ npm -v
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../lib/utils/unsupported.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at C:\Users\dino\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:19:21
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dino\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:92:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
```

After getting this error I updated the node.js to the latest version 8.1.4. 
and the error is same with different line numbers.

```
$ npm -v
module.js:487
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../lib/utils/unsupported.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at C:\Users\dino\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:19:21
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dino\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:92:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
```

What is happening? Any fix to this issue?

Comment: Dude... the latest node is version 8.

Comment: @EvgenyKolyakov The LTS version

Comment: https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/06/node-8-released-lts have a glance

Comment: One of the strongest features they added was the `async await` as built in and no flags needed to run it.

Comment: @EvgenyKolyakov Version 6 or 8 has nothing to do with this error !

Comment: Tried Uninstall and re-install npm??

Comment: Sure... it's just that they changed the core a bit and many packages became deprecated... but besides that.. no way, right.. also.. what npm version are you using ? I have  npm v5.1.0 currently installed

Comment: @Sujith yes. done the same

Comment: @EvgenyKolyakov I have updated my question. Please check

Comment: Try `npm install -g unsupported`

Comment: Btw, what os are you using?

Comment: @EvgenyKolyakov `npm` is not working. How should I run the command `npm install -g unsupported` ?? Windows 8.1 64Bit.

Comment: 1. Try... maybe only -v isn't working. 2. HaHaa ... good luck with that.... haven't used this crap for almost 15 years...

Comment: All the npm commands give the same error

Comment: Sad... wish you best of luck on this one. But please update your question and add the os and npm versions.

Comment: I finally got the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

At last, I got the solution.

I have copied all contents from

> C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm

and pasted it in

> C:\Users\dino\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm